# Multiple plot windows from plotting function in ipython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I have a function that does my plotting. Something like:

```
def myplot(data):     
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(10,10, figsize=(18,12))

    for i in range(10):
        ax[i/10, i%10].imshow(data[i/10, i%10],cmap=plt.cm.gist_yarg,
                      interpolation='nearest', aspect='equal')
    plt.show()

#print the fist plot
myplot(data1)

#print another
myplot(data2)
```

When I run the script using `ipython myscript.py` it will pause after `myplot(data1)` and won't resume until I close the plot window. How can I keep multiple windows open?

Comment: perhaps this will help: http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html#controlling-interactive-updating

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just remove your `plt.show()` from the loop and put it at the end of your script. Every time you create a new figure (as in the `plt.subplots(...)` function), a new window is created.

Comment: But then I will have to wait for the everything to finish. I would like to see the first plot while data2 is being processed.

Comment: The documentation mentions an experimental keyword `block`. Try leaving your `plt.show()` in the loop but replace it with `plt.show(block=False)`. On my machine it gives the desired result, but seems to crash afterwards.